# Python: connecting close dots in 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter-plot

**short:** I want to connect dots that are close to each other in a 3D scatter plot with lines to get some "3D wired look" 3D model.

Background: I got from a microscope an image stack from a fish. I want to show specific cells in that fish. The Software gives me X, Y, Z values of these cells and I'm plotting them in a scatter 3D plot. To get an context I collected a lot of values (XYZ) from the skin too and want to plot them "around" the whole thing to get the look of an fish. If I would be able to connect these dots with lines Id get some kind of "wired" fish which would be great. It would be even greater if id be able to fill the planes in the wire (that would be a 3D fish).

```
#data of the cells
X = np.array(df["X"])
Y = np.array(df["Y"])
Z = np.array(df["Z"])

#data of the fishskin
XF = np.array(df["XF"])
YF = np.array(df["YF"])
ZF = np.array(df["ZF"])

ax.scatter(XF, YF, ZF, s=40, c='b', marker='o')
ax.scatter(XV, YV, ZV, s=40, c='r', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

that's what I did so far, very basic but hey, I'm rookie.
The only language I'm a little into is Python but I also got MatLab and toyed around with Blender a little. **If you think my problem would be a lot easier to solve in one of these programs** (maybe model the fish in blender end import him to Python or whatever) tell me! I was searching around the whole day but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords or something because I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to create an unstructured triangular grid. If this is the case, then I suggest you check out [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triplot_demo.html) on the Matplotlib website.

Comment: Yes, the idea is right but I need it to be automated. Its to much data to do connect the dots manually.